# Splitting a string in chunks using multiprocessing

Tags: python, split, multiprocessing, chunks

I am acquiring data from a microcontroller via UDP. Each packet is a hex string, and I need to split it into equal-sized chunks to do some processing afterwards. However, since the packets are relatively large (about 700 chars each), the time it takes to split one into chunks is larger than the time between packet arrival. This introduces latency and half of the data is lost. I cannot use TCP/IP, because the system needs to operate in real time. How can I multiprocess the following line (can it even be done):

```
list_of_chunks = [packet[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(packet), 16)]
```

Comment: It is quite unlikely multiprocessing can solve your problem. If splitting a short (700 chars is short) string takes too much time to be done between packets, the overhead of interprocess communication probably will be too high too. I'd rather suggest switching to a more efficient implementation (Cython?) or even a more efficient language (C?).

Comment: I guess a queue system may catch in your requirements. May be you can queue packets and use a multi-thread consumer pattern to process them. May be [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is what you are looking for. But not sure, I don't know where you say _real time_ you are talking about a fast reply to somewhere.

Comment: Simple scaling trick for the developer in a hurry: run N copies of your python server listening on ports P..P+N-1. Have your MCU round-robin sequential sends to ports P..P+N-1. Works only as long as your packet processing order doesn't matter.

Comment: You gave me some ideas, which I'll try, thank you.

Comment: Do you need random access to items in the `list_of_chunks`? It would be possible write something that either generated them sequentially one-at-a-time as needed, or alternatively something that quickly gave you any single element that would be in the list without actually creating it (the list). Thus effectively generating the needed chunks, but only as each one is needed). Lastly, since the data is in hex, you can cut its size in half by converting it to binary as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt multiprocessing (or multithreading) will speed up what you want done—too much overhead. Instead consider unwinding the loop. In this case you can write a script that creates the code for you:

Here's what I mean:

```
PACKET_SIZE = 700
packet = [0] * PACKET_SIZE  # dummy packet

#list_of_chunks = [packet[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(packet), 16)]
list_of_chunks = '\n    '.join('packet[{}:{}]'.format(i, i+16)
                                    for i in range(0, len(packet), 16))
print('list_of_chunks = [\n    ' + list_of_chunks + ']')
```

Output:

```
list_of_chunks = [
    packet[0:16]
    packet[16:32]
    packet[32:48]
    packet[48:64]
    packet[64:80]
    packet[80:96]
        ...
    packet[624:640]
    packet[640:656]
    packet[656:672]
    packet[672:688]
    packet[688:704]]
```

Comment: Thank you - it's a neat idea, and I had a similar one. Is there a method of returning the actual values of the packet chunks, by somehow using this list_of_chunks "map"? Because the list elements in list_of_chunks are of string type.

Comment: Alexander: The generated code, **when executed**, will define a variable named `list_of_chunks` which will be a list whose elements are corresponding pieces of `packet`. The idea is that if you know the chunk and packet size in advance, you can have code prewritten for you for that (or those) case(s) and then use that code in your program. While it's certainly possible to also programmatically execute the code generated (or evaluate the expression in it and get back the result), that isn't likely to be any faster than the code with loops in it that you already have).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading 700 Bytes of Data an chunk that afterwards read only 16 Bytes and process it.

For Example:

```
while True:
    chunk = read(16)
    process (chunk)
```

This could also be done in two Processes:

```
#  Process 1
while True:
    chunk = read(16)
    fifo.push (chunk)

#  Process 2
while True:
    chunk = fifo.pop()
    process (chunk)
```